# Lucene KeywordAnalyzer

Tags: lucene

I have a field named "tag". And it contains following data:

## tags

a-b-c-d-e--12-f

a-b

a

I'm using KeywordAnalyzer and searching over this tag field.
"+tag:a-b-c-d-e--12-f"
but it returns zero result.
when i lower the "-" quantity it works. "+tag:a-b-c-d*".

How can i search "a-b-c-d-e--12-f" as a single token. Is The char "-" breaks flow or something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be able to escape special characters using the backslash e.g. \- in this case.

Comment: could not try your solution but i reindexed tag field as Field.Index.NOT_ANALYZED and it works as i expected.